# Why do I get an error on header redirect?

Tags: php, redirect, header, location

I am writing a code where I want to check if the user is logged in and, if yes, redirect the user to the profile page. Else, redirect the user to the login page. But I'm getting an ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS on the browser.
This is my code:

```
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
    header("location: profile.php");
    exit();
} else {
    header("location: login.php");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Is this code added to all your PHP files?

Comment: page A sends you to page B which sends you to page A again. Sometimes it can be a cookie problem, sometimes it's a flawed application logic

Comment: Thanks My mistake was the above code was inside the same login.php, so it keeps redirecting to the same page. I created another file where I pasted the code and it worked. Thanks for the support.